# negative verb confusion

Tags: conjugations

Slightly mundane question here. Do negative verbs  translate as x "does not" do this action or simply "not" e.g　食べない "not eat" as opposed to "does not eat". The reason I ask is because On Tae kim's site all the verb examples are translated as "does not", When suddenly 買わない becomes "not buy" - which is it? I know it's a silly a question, but I'm pretty curious, so I'd really appreciate any answers.

Comment: What would this mean, what is the difference? Negative constructions with ない are themselves conjugatable again, which is a feature shared by the English expression "does not do <verb>, eg. _食べなかった_ -> _did not do <verb>_.

Comment: If you expect to be able to translate between English and Japanese in a word-by-word way, I'm afraid you're in for a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 7):

In English, the auxiliary verb *do* is a meaningless verb that is inserted for various reasons.  For example, direct questions require an auxiliary verb in modern English:

> 1a. *Like you the movie?
>    1b. Do you like the movie?

When you form an English question like this, the subject and auxiliary swap places.  But the lexical verb *like* isn't an auxiliary, so example 1a is ungrammatical.  You insert *do* so that you have an auxiliary to switch with the subject.

And in modern English, you need an auxiliary to add the negative *not* or negative affix *-n't*:

> 2a. *She takes not the money. / *She takesn't the money.
>    2b. She does not take the money. / She doesn't take the money.

The examples in 2a don't work because *take* is a lexical verb.  In this kind of English sentence, you can only negate an auxiliary verb, so you insert the meaningless verb *do*.

---

Japanese is completely different.  It has a negator `-(a)nai` which attaches directly to verb stems.  There's no need to insert anything like *do*, so whether or not you translate it with *do* depends on what's required in English.  It has nothing to do with Japanese.

To form the negative in Japanese, attach `-(a)nai` to the stem of a verb:

```
　食べる　　tabe-ru　　　　　
　食べない　tabe-nai
```

The stem `tabe-` ends in a vowel, so you add `-nai` without the `(a)`.

```
　話す　　　hanas-u
　話さない　hanas-anai
```

The stem `hanas-` ends in a consonant, so you add `-anai` **with** the `(a)`.  Adding this extra vowel prevents you from saying the consonants /s/ and /n/ with nothing in-between, which Japanese doesn't allow.

Your example 買う is a consonant stem verb, too, even though it doesn't look like one.  The stem is `kaw-`, so you insert the `(a)`:

```
　買う　　　kaw-u
　買わない　kaw-anai
```

The reason this seems weird is that /w/ disappears before every vowel except /a/.  So the /w/ disappears from `kaw-u`, and you're left with `kau` (買う).

The main exception to this pattern is ある, which becomes ない instead of *あらない.  And there are other negators (such as ん in ません, used to form a polite negative).  But I'm limiting this discussion to ない, since that's the negator you asked about.

As you can see, there's nothing corresponding to *do* in these Japanese examples.  Whether you translate these with *do* or not depends entirely on the requirements of English, and has nothing to do with the Japanese.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with `She takes not the money`, other than it makes you sound like you're from Victorian-era England.

Comment: @istrasci That's exactly what's wrong with it.  It's not modern English.  (It's fine, of course, if you want to use an archaism!)

Comment: Well that doesn't make it "wrong", just "out of use".  Splitting hairs I guess...  Although I now see that you said, "In modern English", which I guess I missed before.

Answer (score 1):

Tae Kim sometimes uses over-literal translations.  I'm guessing the one that confused you was "[As for me, not buy](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/negverb.html)" (私は買わない).

Without context, this could mean:

1) A specific statement about the future: I'm not going to buy/I won't buy (thing we were talking about)

2) A more general statement about your habits: I don't buy (thing we were talking about)

Comment: Ugh.  “(1) アリスは食べない。- As for Alice, does not eat. […] (5) 私は買わない。- As for me, not buy.”  Why did the author write _does_ in (1)?  It is not the correct English anyway, and comparing these two sentences, the OP’s confusion is pretty much expected.

Comment: Don't know why, but I have seen other people confused by some of by some of the Tae Kim translations, so it's not just our OP.